# How to not let maven download the transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

We use a third party application which comes with jackson jars. The version of these jars is 2.12. We have customized this application and added some more dependencies (i.e. jwks-rsa, java-jwt). These additional dependencies have transitive dependency on jackson and uses older version of jackson.

As a result, the additional dependencies (i.e. jwks-rsa, java-jwt) downloads older version jackson and place them in our codebase.

How do I make them not to download the jackson jars? Below are the additional dependencies in our pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-entity-filtering</artifactId>
            <version>2.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look into the `<exclusions>` element?

Comment: Yup. Just implemented and works fine. Thanks!

Comment: If those others use older versions of jackson define jackson in your own pom file ...